# How do i fix this? "Unsupported operand type(s)"

Tags: python

```
import random 
athletes = ["John","Mike","Jack","Steve","Bob"]
judges = ["Judge1","Judge2","Judge3"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
def score():
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  judge_scores = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2]
  final = int(judge_scores)
  final_2 = sum(final)
  print(final_2)


i = 0
while i <= 4:
    athlete = athletes[i]
    print(athlete + " scored:")
    score()
    i += 1
    if i > 4:
        break
```

I'm trying to make this code return the sum of the random scores given by the judges for each individual athlete but I encounter an error saying that

> int object is not iterable.

I've changed it around a little bit with no luck and this was the original bit of code that I think was the closest:

```
import random 
athletes = ["John","Mike","Jack","Steve","Bob"]
judges = ["Judge1","Judge2","Judge3"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
def score():
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  judge_scores = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2]
  final = sum(judge_scores)
  print(final)


i = 0
while i <= 4:
    athlete = athletes[i]
    print(athlete + " scored:")
    score()
    i += 1
    if i > 4:
        break
```

Again I encounter an error.  This time I get this error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: I am pretty sure that your code snippet is not complete and you assigns number to athletes somewhere

Comment: Your `numbers` are strings. Use integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the string value in number list into int like this:

```
import random 
athletes = ["John","Mike","Jack","Steve","Bob"]
judges = ["Judge1","Judge2","Judge3"]
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def score():
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  judge_scores = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2]

  print(judge_scores)


i = 0
while i <= 4:
    athlete = athletes[i]
    print(athlete + " scored:")
    score()
    i += 1
    if i > 4:
        break
```

or you can use

```
import random 
athletes = ["John","Mike","Jack","Steve","Bob"]
judges = ["Judge1","Judge2","Judge3"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
def score():
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  judge_scores = int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1]) + int(numbers[2])

  print(judge_scores)


i = 0
while i <= 4:
    athlete = athletes[i]
    print(athlete + " scored:")
    score()
    i += 1
    if i > 4:
        break
```

Comment: okay it's working now, thanks for the help. I really should've noticed that earlier, bit of a silly mistake.

Comment: pleasure all mine

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a list with numbers as str try to change the  numbers to 
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 1):

judge score in string and `sum` works on int type, you need to convert the stirng to int first then do sum operation

```
import random 
athletes = ["John","Mike","Jack","Steve","Bob"]
judges = ["Judge1","Judge2","Judge3"]
numbers = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
def score():
  random.shuffle(numbers)
  judge_scores = [numbers[0] , numbers[1] , numbers[2]]
  final = sum(map(int,judge_scores))
  print(final)


i = 0
while i <= 4:
    athlete = athletes[i]
    print(athlete + " scored:")
    score()
    i += 1
    if i > 4:
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sum` takes an iterable and sums its values. In your case, `numbers` contains strings, so it concatenates the strings: `('2', '5', '7')` goes to `'257'`.
Change your `numbers` list in `[1,2,...]` and everything will be ok.

Also, you can just type

```
numbers = list(range(10))
```